# Logging Messages from Java Class back to the Karate Report

Tags: karate

We have a scenario where we have to post a json request and then validate few actions in the UI. So we have a karate feature file which hits a request and after that we are invoking a java class from within the feature file. The java class would run the Selenium Webdriver test of us. In the java methods we have few Assertions/Info Messages which we would like to log back to the Karate Reports.

Is there a way in Karate with which we can write these messages from my Java Class to the Karate Test Reports?

Comment: Please Add appropriate tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Karate [parallel runner](https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution) it is designed to collect anything logged to package [`com.intuit.karate`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/cucumber/ReporterLogAppender.java#L49), which will then appear in the [cucumber-html-report](https://github.com/intuit/karate#test-reports).

So you can try [using the same slf4j `Logger`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/ScriptEnv.java#L61) - and it might work.

A better way might be to just [return a `Map` back to Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java) from your Java code, with all the information you need to log. Then all you need to do is use the [`print`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#print) keyword. I would recommend this approach actually, it should be less complicated and it does not assume that you are using the Cucumber HTML reporting. You could even do Karate asserts with the `match` keyword on the JSON that you get, refer to this example: [`dogs.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/dogs/dogs.feature).

Comment: We will take a look at the above suggestions.

Comment: @Peter Thomas Please provide an updated link for sl4j logger. I'm unable to get the log in the cucmber report.

Comment: @CVA sorry assume that this is not supported. unless this link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57079152/143475

Comment: @PeterThomas Just figured that out myself & added the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63383527/1751801

Answer (score 1):

We did try logging back to “com.intuit.karate” as shown below and its logging to the ‘overview-features.html’ report

Logger in Java class :

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.intuit.karate");

However we made an observation that if an exception is thrown from the java class the exception would appear first and then followed by all the information that is logged, both looks to exist as a different piece in the report.

For e.g

This is sample method with logger in the java class which i am invoking from the feature file

```
 public void myTestMethod() {
    logger.info("Starting Test");
    logger.info("Setting path of chrome driver");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe"); //driver doesnt exist in this path
    logger.info("invoking chrome"); // we would expect the exception to be thrown after this line
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    logger.info("perform search in google");
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Selenium");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).submit();
    driver.quit();
}
```

But in the reports the exception appears first and then all the information that is logged from the java class. Both looks like two different  pieces in the report, please see the report here https://www.screencast.com/t/bBhAIj7WKj

In the above case would it be possible to have the exception thrown after the line where we log” invoking Chrome” i think this would make it easier to identify the test failures from the reports. Please let us know if this would be possible

Comment: it took me a while to see this, because I did not get a notification, you may need to use SO differently, e.g. opening a new question is ok. about your request, that's going to be hard to implement, because it will have the effect of making the log bloated for normal scenarios. you can do a try catch and add an extra log WITH the error object. also try the second approach I suggested.

Comment: The try catch with the extra logger resolves our issue for now. We will also take a look at the second approach which you had suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me by passing the karate object from the javascript file to the java code. With this I was able to call the `karate.log` function from the Java code. This way I could see the messages on the report.