# Add console output to Cucumber HTML report

Tags: cucumber, karate

I would like to add console output of tests to the Cucumber HTML report as shown here
[image: Report]

How do i set this or do i need to write some code in the Test Runner?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly refer to the instructions here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report

This will give you the report that you see in your question.

If you use the `print` keyword, that will also appear.

And also refer to the answers to this question: [Logging Messages from Java Class back to the Karate Report](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47366624/143475)