# How to throw a customised error in the karate final report using LoggerFactory?

Tags: karate

From a java class, I wanted a customized error to be shown in the cucumber html report

Tried the following syntax to achieve this, but no failures were seen in the cucumber html report.

```
     public static  org.slf4j.Logger logger = 
 LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.intuit.karate");

public static void myMethod() 
  {
int a=1;
int b=3;
if(a!=b) {
logger.error("bla bla");
         }
 }
```

My parallel runner class file looks something like this

```
@KarateOptions(tags = {"~@ignore"})
public class Controller {


@Test
public void testParallel() {
    System.setProperty("karate.env", "acpt"); 
Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 1);
    generateReport(results.getReportDir());
    assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);
}

public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
    Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
    List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
    jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "EPP");
    ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
    reportBuilder.generateReports();
}
}
```

Comment: You can see if the hint in this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57079152/143475

Else assume that this is not supported.