# How can I get Karate logs printed in the report?

Tags: java, karate

I have

```
<logger name="com.intuit.karate" level="DEBUG"/>
```

in my logback-test.xml. But when I run my tests I see that when the step

```
* assert SchemaUtils.isValid(response, schema)
```

fails, I do not see any debug information in the Cucumber report (with the payload and description on which field is missing or which value is wrong), like:

```
error: object instance has properties which are not allowed by the schema: ["PrSKU"]
        level: "error"
```

I do see it in the console though:

```
{content_type=, value=21:54:25.380 assertion failed: assert evaluated to false: SchemaUtils.isValid(response, schema)21:54:25.413
```

How can I get logs printed in the report?

I found how to access previous request/response and the print it in the report:

```
// setup global hook to log details only on failed scenarios
    karate.configure('afterScenario', function(){
        var info = karate.info;
        if(info.errorMessage) {
            karate.log('failed',info.scenarioType+':',info.scenarioName);
            var r = karate.prevRequest;
            if(r) {
                var log = 'request: ' + r.method + ' ' + r.uri + '\n' + karate.pretty(r.headers)
                if(r.body) log += '\n' + karate.pretty(r.body)
                karate.log(log);
                karate.log('response: ' + karate.pretty(response));
            }
        }
    })
```

But I did not find the way how to access karate logs and then print them in the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `SchemaUtils.isValid(response, schema)` seems to be custom Java code, I think if you throw any `Exception` the error message will be printed by Karate and should appear in the log as well as HTML report. If it does not, it can be a bug - so please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks Peter
Yes, Throwing an exception works and the message appears in the report.
I am trying to find another way how to do that without failing the test with the exception.

Comment: @EvgenyTkachenko isn't it simple. return a `Map` that has 2 entrires - a boolean `result` and a String `message`. then just use `print`

Comment: Thanks
That's the option I will go with. I hoped there is the way to post all logs or error logs from Java to the katate cucumber report

Comment: @EvgenyTkachenko you can if you don't mind importing `com.intuit.karate.Logger` and also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57079152/143475

Comment: import com.intuit.karate.Logger;
private static final Logger LOGGER = new  Logger();
LOGGER.info("1!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

@Peter This helps to log to the console or to the file but not to the Cucumber report
Thanks for helping me out

Comment: The problem is that I do not see any logs in the cucumber-html report. I use karate 0.9.4 and parallel runner and logback.xml with <logger name="com.intuit.karate" level="DEBUG"/>

Comment: @EvgenyTkachenko follow this process if you think this is a problem: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue